# Rails -- Using a method with an equals at the end?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In Michael Hartl's tutorial he has a `module SessionsHelper`, which has a method called `current_user=` which accepts a parameter and assigns it to `@current_user`.  He then invokes this in various other methods in his program using a line like `current_user = User.first`.

My question is how we know that the `current_user=` method is being called at all -- it seems to me that what would actually be happening is a new variable called `current_user` is created on the spot, given the value of `User.first`, and then when the function closes that variable dies.

I also tested this simply by creating the following code:

```
def x= val
puts "method called"
end

x = 46
puts x
```

This code snippet simply prints 46 on the screen - the function `x=` is never called at all.  So what is the `current_user=` method doing in Michael Hartl's tutorial, and how does he cause that function to be called?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because Ruby treat expressions that can be read as simple variable as simple variable. You can see it with this code:

```
def x
  10
end

print x      #=> 10
x = 5
print x      #=> 5
print x()    #=> 10
print self.x #=> 10
```

This is the same case. Look:

```
def x=(a)
  print a
end

x = 8      #=> Variable 'x' assigned to 8
x=(8)      #=> The same

self.x = 8 #=> Function called
```

Also remember that assignment functions (like the last one) can't return any value, the return value will always be the last argument.

```
def x=(a)
  return a+1
end

var = (self.x = 8) #=> Function called; Variable 'var' assigned to 8
```

Answer (score 0):

A common complaint from Rubyists is that it's sometimes hard to tell when you're referring to a variable or a method. Here's an attempt to explain how it works, using my admittedly limited understanding.

Ruby does not have a concept of "object attributes," at least not in the same way as most other languages. If your object has an instance variable called @current_user, it is completely inaccessible to anything outside that object (instance_variable_get and instance_variable_set aside - here there be dragons.) The *only way* to get or set @current_user from outside is to define "current_user" and/or "current_user=" methods (or "attr_accessor :current_user", which does the same thing.)

So when you call "obj.current_user = user", some syntactic sugar is invoked, and Ruby knows you're just calling the current_user= method. After all, since you can't access instance variables externally, there is simply nothing else it could mean.

When you're inside the object you would need to call current_user= with "self.current_user = user". Otherwise you're right, it would just create a local variable. And since Ruby's quite consistent in its OO design, this is exactly what's happening in your example. "x = 5" is just creating a local variable, but "self.x = 5" would call the x= method.

Answer (score 0):

Note: as the other answers suggest, x= and self.x= perform different functionalities.

Within the scope of the SessionsHelper, I believe the common usage is to use that module as a mixin for a class.

Consider the following:

```
class Foo
  include SessionsHelper
  def foo_current_user
    puts 'foo' + current_user
  end
end

class Bar
  include SessionsHelper
  def bar_current_user
    puts 'bar' + current_user
  end
end
```

His module thus allows you to do `Foo.new.foo_current_user()` and `Bar.new.bar_current_user()` while adhering to the DRY principle.

It stores the values into the instance variable @current_user in both classes. Outside of a class, the mixin module may well not make much sense.